# How to get pylab to work in eclipse pydev?

Tags: eclipse, matplotlib, pydev, ipython

It seems interactive plotting using pylab/matplotlib does not work in pyDev. After for example:

```
pylab
x=linspace(0,10,1000)
plot(x,x*x)
```

nothing is plotted in the figure window, and the window is not responding.

Is there any way to get pylab to work properly in pyDev? I am using matplotlib version 1.2.0 and the backend is TkAgg.

Comment: What backend and version of mpl are you using?  `matplotlib.__version__` and `matplotlib.get_backend()`

Comment: Version of mpl is 1.2.0 and the backend is TkAgg.

Comment: Please edit that detail (version and backend) into the question.  I suspect you are having issues with the gui main loops.